# Conway Proposition, Runge's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

In Proposition VIII.1.1 in Conway's book *Functions of one complex variable I* we have the following proposition [image]

Now the proof is carried out by dividing the complex plane into a rectangular grid which is sufficiently small and then choosing the collection of squares in the grid which intersect $K$. One then deletes every side of a square which lies on two squares, the remaining sides will be the $\gamma_k$.

**Now how does one verify that these form a finite number of closed polygons?** Intuitively this is obvious. However the best argument I could come up with was that one first realizes that the end points of $\gamma_k$ must intersect with another curve $\gamma_{j}$. Doing so we obtain a chain of curves $\gamma_{k_1},\dotsc,\gamma_{k_m},\dotsc$. At some point we must have repetition of some of the line segments and so we can remove a closed polygon. We then remove the closed polygon from our collection and realize that we can again assume that every line segment intersects another line segment which does not lie on the polygon. We can then continue in this fashion.

Is there some way to motivate this more clearly? Is there something wrong with this argument?

Comment: Rudin treats this problem in his Real and Complex Analysis p. 268 by defining  "balanced" oriented plane intervals and proving from this that the cycles involved in Runge are finite.

Comment: Ah thanks. His proof is clear